# JS match.Media with media query range

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I am having an issue getting my site to respond to matchMedia query **range** using media.Match.

Updates based on comments: I need to use match.Media instead of CSS media queries because i need to check if a component is present and if true, i then need to add a class to another element if the browser size is between 1400 - 1800px. Also, i do need this to fire every time the browser is resized.

To troubleshoot, I have tried:

1. Using a single matchMedia('(min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1800px)')
2. Doing a single match (using only min-width: 1400px) and that succeeds. However, when I add in my 2nd variable 'mq.Max' and 'and statement', the whole thing fails.
3. I have read through MDN and still not seeing how to implement this.

JS below, thank you for any suggestions you may have.

```
if (jQuery('.jump-nav').length) {
// Create a condition that targets viewports at least 770px wide
window.onresize = function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    var mqMin = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1400px)');
    var mqMax = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1800px)');
    // check if media query matches@media (min-width: 30em) and (orientation: landscape)
    if (mqMin.matches && mqMax.matches) {
        console.log('Media Query Matched!')
        // add css class for desktop
        $('.rowComponent').addClass('jn-rowchange');
    } else {
        // remove css class if not desktop
        $('.rowComponent').removeClass('jn-rowchange');
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Why not combine `mqMin` and `mqMax`? `matchMedia('(min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1800px)')`

Comment: Should have specified that i tried that...updating this now

Comment: Your also recreating the queries every time the window is resized. Create them outside then check matches inside.

Comment: Depending on why you are doing it, you can just use CSS instead. So If its simply about styling you could have your CSS media query for that size and within the query have CSS like `.rowComponent.jn-rowchange{}` etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is something that worked for me!

```
let mqMin = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
let mqMax = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)");

window.onresize = function () {
  if (mqMin.matches && mqMax.matches) {
    console.log("Inside Query parameter!");
  } else {
    console.log("Outside Query parameter!");
  }
};
```